# bash. unicode. история

Tags: linux, bash

Добрый день.

Опять примитивный вопрос по bash.
Ранее я пользовался встроенным в busybox шеллом `Almquist shell`, но решил перейти на `bash`. Этим я решил некоторые проблемы эстетики, но появились новые, причем скорее функциональные.

Вот такой фрагмент содержится у меня в .bash_history и вот такие пункты истории я получаю, если пытаюсь ее перебирать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, как нетрудно догадаться, таким образом представлены обычные пути.
Вдобавок, история засорена непонятными командами типа **pwd>&9;kill -STOP $$**. Как я догадываюсь, они связаны с выгрузкой системы, хотя определенной зависимости в истории не видно. Я связываю это потому, что когда я набираю в консоли алиас **sudo reboot** (rb), в этой же tty автоматически выполняется команда logout. После нажатия ввода выводится не только новая строка приветствия, но после нее впечатана команда **logout**. И вот после этого уже система выгружается. При этом, сама команда logout в истории почему-то не сохраняется. Вообще сохраняется как-то нелинейно. Я могу не знать чего-то о том, как баш хранит свою историю, но когда я начал им пользоваться - появился этот файл, других я не вижу. *В каждой tty своя история, а файл один.* Словом, выглядит несколько путано, может быть, нетрудно будет кому-то прояснить?

**Почему в истории появляется содержимое такого странного вида?**

Comment: 1. в чём состоит ваш вопрос? конкретизируйте, пожалуйста. 2. вероятно, если вы начнёте конкретизировать, получится несколько вопросов. задавайте их, пожалуйста, каждый **отдельно**. лимита на количество вопросов, насколько мне известно, движком сайта не предусмотрено. если необходимо сослаться на информацию из другого вопроса, можно вставить ссылку. это тоже не запрещено.

Comment: **pwd>&9;kill -STOP $$** появляется, если я запускаю процесс выгрузки системы при запущенном `mc` в одной из **tty**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

какая именно программа генерирует у вас эти наборы команд `cd ...` — можно лишь догадываться. вполне возможно, что делает это упомянутый вами т.н. «файл-менеджер».

возможно, избавиться от их появления в истории вам поможет использование переменной `HISTCONTROL`. в частности, добавление в `.bashrc` такой, например, строки:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
```

подробности смотрите в `man bash` в секции *shell variables* раздела *parameters*.

Comment: При включенной переменной мусор все равно возникал в истории, хоть и начинался с пробела. Суть в том, что переменная была активна в видимых сессиях bash (там, где она была установлена). А мусор возникал в результате неочевидной сессии, работающей "внутри" mc. При запуске mc с опцией -u (без сопровождающей суб-сессии bash) мусор перестал появляться, так как переменная управления историей, активная в ттерминале, откуда запускался mc, оставалась активной и при его работе.